# What's the proper way to use namespacing for Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use proper namespacing for my Rails API using api/v1/whatever_class. When generating my resources I did `rails g resource api/v1/games` plus the params. It migrated without an issue.

I tested it out in my seed file by writing `Api::V1::Game.create(params)` and it even seeded without an issue.

However, when I jump into the console, `Api::V1::Game.count` returns a 0. It should be 1.

Am I doing this right? Is this the best way?

Comment: If it was a namespace error you wouldn't have any count value, but an exception

Comment: Are you sure it actually created the record? Change your seed to `create!` and see if there is an error raised because `create` (without the bang) will not raise an error on failure.